# Responsive styles and jQuery .show()/.hide()

Tags: jquery, css

jQuery's .show and .hide methods appear to inspect the display value of the element and tries to restore it, but does so as an inline style that can adversely affect less-specific styles (for example, a responsive stylesheet that alters the layout of elements which you'd also want to show or hide with jQuery).

Here's an example:

Markup

```
<div class="parent altLayout">
  <div class="child">hi</div>
</div>
```

Styles

```
.parent {
    height: 40px;
    background: #06f;
    padding: 30px;
}

.child {
    height: 40px;    
    background: #eef;
}

.altLayout .child {
    display: inline;
}
```

JavaScript

```
// Uncomment each block to see the effect

// w/o altLayout
/* * /
$('.parent').removeClass('altLayout');
/* */

// remove before hide/show
/* * /
$('.parent').removeClass('altLayout');
$('.child').hide();
$('.child').show();
/* */

// remove after hide/show
/* * /
$('.child').hide();
$('.child').show();
$('.parent').removeClass('altLayout');
/* */
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jinglesthula/ZttLJ/

(Here I roughly simulate what could happen at different breakpoints for a media query that would alternately apply the styles covered by .altLayout.  The code given could also be a legitimate use case as opposed to responsive media queries.)

As near as I can tell, the lingering inline display style is causing the inconsistency.  My question is whether there's a way around this?  Maybe this is a flaw in the approach for .show/.hide where it's assumed that the original computed value can be introduced as an inline style without impacting other code.

Comment: As a side note, I'm currently using a .hide class that just specifies display:none and then using .addClass('hide') and .removeClass('hide') but that seems like a clunky workaround.

Comment: Bug/feature request filed: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/15037

Comment: Looks like there is some traction on addressing it: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/15037#comment:3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `show` and `hide` are fairly assertive statements. Consider a common use case of someone who sets an object to be hidden by default (either by using a class with `display: none` or by an inline style doing the same thing) who then calls `show` after a suitable event. They want that element to show up, regardless. The only way to reliably do that is by setting an inline style.

As a personal preference, I tend to use `show` and `hide` pretty sparingly, since the side effects of removing an element can cause undesired layout issues, as you've identified. Instead, I usually `toggleClass` on the appropriate element (often times, a parent of the element I no longer want to display) to reflect the new state.

Comment: I'm ok with show and hide being assertive as far as making the element show up and disappear - the issue I'm dealing with is that in the example given it does more than just 'show' and 'hide' the element - it also cements the computed display value, which causes issues.  I guess toggleClass is similar to what I use, which may be the best workaround (e.g. avoiding use of show/hide).